# How to take user input and set struct value without having predefined character?

Tags: c

I have a main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    UserOptions opt;
    opt = GetDefaultOptions();
    /* Override defaults with requested options */
    HandleArgs(&opt, &argc, &argv);
}
```

A struct called `UserOptions`:

```
typedef struct {
   int codewords;
   int mode; 
   char *separator;
} UserOptions;
```

The `GetDefaultOptions()` sets some default values to `UserOptions` unless these are explicitly provided by the user in which case `HandleArgs()` sets them as follows:

```
HandleArgs(UserOptions *opt, int *argcp, char **argvp[]) {
    int optchr;
    int longIndex;
    struct option longOptions[] = {
        {"codewords", required_argument, NULL, 'c'},
        {"mode", no_argument, NULL, 'D'}, 
        {"separator", no_argument, NULL, ' /* Something here */ '},
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
    };

    for (;;) {
        optchr = getopt_long(*argcp, *argvp, "c:D: /* ??? */ ",
        longOptions, &longIndex);
        switch (optchr) {
            case 'c':
                opt->codewords = 1;
                break;
             case 'D':
                opt->mode = 1;
                break;
             /* something to set opt->separator to user defined separator */
             default:
                return 0;
                break;
         }
    }
}
```

I want to set the separator as defined by the user and not to some predefined value like `\n`. For example if the user enters `|` or `>` as the separator then, `opt->separator` should be set to `|` or `>`.

EDIT: 
I would like to use the separator provided by the user in a function. Right now I am doing it like

```
if (tempBuffer[i] != '\n') {
    /* Do something */
}
```

Instead I would like to have it like:

```
if (tempBuffer[i] != opt->separator) {
    /* Do something */
}
```

where opt->separator could be `|` or `>` as provided by the user.

Comment: You would need to know the maximum number of characters that you may have as options (including `opt->separator` so you can provide storage for the for the combined `"c:D:"` and whatever your `opt->separator` is, The concatenate the strings together in that block of memory and use that in `getopt_long`. Like `char options[32] = "";` then `strcpy (options, "c:D:"); strcat (options, opt->separator);` and then `optchr = getopt_long(*argcp, *argvp, options, ...`  *note:* `opt->separator` must be a *nul-terminated* string in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opt->separator I assume would be set prior to calling HandleArgs. So:

```
HandleArgs(UserOptions *opt, int *argcp, char **argvp[]) {
    int optchr;
    int longIndex;
    struct option longOptions[] = {
        {"codewords", required_argument, NULL, 'c'},
        {"mode", no_argument, NULL, 'D'}, 
        {"separator", no_argument, NULL, *opt->separator},
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
    };
```

At this point I would dynamically create the option string from the contents of the structure, so something like: (note: you did not give the definition of options structure so making it up)

```
char getopt_string[SOME_MAX_SIZE]="";
for (struct options* o=longOptions;o->first_field != NULL; o++)
{
   strncat(getopt_string, &o->forth_field, 1);
   strcat(getopt_string,":");
}
```

Then loop as normal:

```
for (;;) {
    optchr = getopt_long(*argcp, *argvp, getopt_string,
    longOptions, &longIndex);
}
```

There is a little disconnect now because you have explicit values in the switch statement, for values created dynamically from longOptions. You could have a number of function pointers in a table to make this completely dynamic (for example, add function pointer to the options structure)

You cannot dynamically change a case value, so you need to handle the separator in the default section:

```
switch (optchr) {
    ...
    default:
       if (optchr == opt->separator) 
           return DmtxSeparator;  // ?? :)

       return DmtxFail;
       break;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain this part a bit more? "At this point I would dynamically create the option string from the contents of the structure, so something like: (note: you did not give the definition of options structure so making it up)"
What is the purpose of the for loop here?

Comment: Added clarification to the question.

Comment: Imagine adding a new option (v: for verbose for example). You would need to add (1) an entry to longOptions, you would need to (2) manually add "V:" to the string. You would have to add (3) a "case 'V': to the switch. Ideally you should only add to (1) and (3) - 1 defines the option, 3 responds to it. The loop auto-generates (2) from the contents of (1)

Comment: To add to your answer, instead of putting the condition in the `default` condition, I created a separate switch case putting the following: 
case 'S':   opt->separator = optarg; break;
This takes the input as specified by the user.